# Unexpected TypeError when using reduce function

Tags: python, typeerror, reduce, higher-order-functions, iterable

Here is the line of code:

```
product = list(reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, [2,2,2,2,2]))
```

Error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: The result of `reduce()` was a single int - why are you trying to apply `list()` to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to put your result in a list, you can use this code:

```
import functools
product = [functools.reduce((lambda x,y:x*y),[2,2,2,2,2])]
print(product)
```

The list function cannot be used because it corresponds to a type conversion which is not possible as your result is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, [2,2,2,2,2])
32
```

So you can't make a `list` of it.

Comment: Well you *can*, but the way to do it is `[32]`, not `list(32)`.

Comment: I wouldn't call it making a list from it, though, it's a list containing the value.  If we're nitpicking =)